# Checking for identical strings in array inside JSON object

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm working with this code and can't figure out how to solve said problem. I have this simple loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
  var ht = $('<div class="empresa"><div class="ordem"><div class="ordem_e">Ordem:1</div><div class="nome_e">Nome da empresa</div></div><div class="responsaveis"><p class="nome_r">Nome do cidadão</p><span class="ordem_p">Ordem:1</span><br /><p class="funcao">Contratante</p><br /><div class="cont_status"><div class="ind_assinar">Assinar</div><div class="ind_aprovar">Aprovar</div><div class="ind_aceitar">Aceitar</div></div></div></div>')

  ht.find(".ordem_e").text('Ordem:' + z[i].papel_ordem);
  ht.find(".nome_e").text(z[i].empr_nome);
  ht.find(".nome_r").text(z[i].cont_nome);
  ht.find(".ordem_p").text("Ordem:" + z[i].cont_ordem);
  ht.find(".funcao").text(z[i].decl_identificacao);

  $(".insere_empr").append(ht);
}
```

which just creates some objects displaying some properties, like in this screenshot:

[image]

The "z" in code where I get the values, is a JSON returned from a Ajax call. It's an array with objects inside, like [{...},{...},{...},{...}]

So, how can I compare one element (in my code in .nome_e text, or the "Magna" name in the picture) to check for identical elements? I would then like to unite said html objects which had the same name (again, based on the screen shot, "Magna" would get two boxes inside).

I'm still trying some ways to found a solution, but it seems I'm lost right now. I will keep trying, but if someone can point me some ideas on how to fix that, it would help a lot.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if the post seems long. I tried to make my question clear.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Am I right in thinking that what you need to do is *group* the contents on `z` by the property `empr_nome`?

Comment: yeah, I need to group the two elements with same empr_nome (in the case Magna)

Answer (score 0):

You can build an index of already used keys (object) to ignore identical elements:

```
let idx = {};
for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    if (!idx[z[i].empr_nome]) {
        idx[z[i].empr_nome] = 1;
        var ht = $('<div class="empresa"><div class="ordem"><div class="ordem_e">Ordem:1</div><div class="nome_e">Nome da empresa</div></div><div class="responsaveis"><p class="nome_r">Nome do cidadão</p><span class="ordem_p">Ordem:1</span><br /><p class="funcao">Contratante</p><br /><div class="cont_status"><div class="ind_assinar">Assinar</div><div class="ind_aprovar">Aprovar</div><div class="ind_aceitar">Aceitar</div></div></div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed it like that:

```
var wha = [];

        for (i=0; i<z.length; i++){

        var ht = $('<div class="empresa"><div class="ordem"><div class="ordem_e">Ordem:1</div><div class="nome_e">Nome da empresa</div></div><div class="responsaveis"><p class="nome_r">Nome do cidadão</p><span class="ordem_p">Ordem:1</span><br /><p class="funcao">Contratante</p><br /><div class="cont_status"><div class="ind_assinar">Assinar</div><div class="ind_aprovar">Aprovar</div><div class="ind_aceitar">Aceitar</div></div></div></div>')

          ht.find(".ordem_e").text('Ordem:' + z[i].papel_ordem);
          ht.find(".nome_e").text(z[i].empr_nome);
          var gh = ht.find(".nome_e").text();
          ht.find(".nome_r").text(z[i].cont_nome);
          ht.find(".ordem_p").text("Ordem:" + z[i].cont_ordem);
          ht.find(".funcao").text(z[i].decl_identificacao);

          //console.log(z[i].empr_nome);
          console.log(wha);
          console.log($.inArray(gh, wha));

          if($.inArray(gh, wha) == -1){
            wha.push(z[i].empr_nome);
          } else{
            ht.find(".nome_e").parents().css("background-color", "orange");
          }

          $(".insere_empr").append(ht);

        }
```

Made a empty array, compare the item string with said array. If -1, push it (just for reference). By the way, the orange bkg is just for testing. Now I just need to figure it out how to acess the upper structure. Maybe I will ask later.